# how to resolve errors in the module manager, Step 1: Readiness Check, occurs when enabling the extension?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am experiencing an error in the Magento 2.3.3 module manager when I want to enable the plugin (extension) error, the following picture:

[image]

I have tried to increase memory_limit and see other references but have not found the right answer

system operasi : windows 10 64bit

PHP Version 7.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! after googling I got the success both in windows and linux (Ubuntu). I need to run the cron, before try to install module in magento.

Open terminal and enter the following line in the terminal.

```
cd <magento_root_directory>
```

then execute the following 3 commands in terminal.

```
php bin/magento cron:run

php update/cron.php

php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Then try to install the module from magento 2.3 admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

After making changes into php.ini file, please stop and restart server. You have to clear cookies of browser as well.

**For missing php extensions**

Go to your php root folder,

Simply copy all icu* * * *.dll files:

from

C:\xampp\php

to

C:\xampp\apache\bin

intl extension will start working!!!

Restart server as well if it doesn't work.